# Position fixed with min width?

Tags: html, css, fixed

I am trying to add a min width to a div that uses a fixed position. I'm not sure if its possible my code below works fine if I remove the fixed positioning.

What I am trying to achieve is to protect the text in the red area (contains links) from being resized below certain 200px;

EDIT THIS IS THE FULL CODE

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#header{
height:60px;
width:100%;
background-color:#000;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
}

#leftdiv{
    width:15%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#ED6062;
    float:left;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:60px;   
    min-width:100px;
    }
#middlediv{
    width:25%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#F0E92B;
    float:left;
    position:fixed; 
    left:15%;
    top:60px;
    }
#rightdiv{
    width:60%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#26D978;
    float:left;
    position:fixed;
    left:40%;
    top:60px;   
    }       


</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id='header'></div>
<div id='leftdiv'>Contains links</div>
<div id='middlediv'></div>
<div id='rightdiv'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/85mpvxo7/

Comment: this working. try `min-width:1200px`

Comment: If you fix the elements you don't need the `float: left`. Maybe that's causing the problem, `min-width` should work for fixed elements. Also, maybe the `width: 25%` is bigger than 160px, in a resolution bigger than 640px, 25% is more than 160px. What's your window size?

Comment: Check this fiddle, it works just fine https://jsfiddle.net/e0rydh23/

Comment: @arieljuod I've tried on a few screens sizes. I've updated the original code to show a full example of the layout I use and the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `min-width` works as expected, your problem is that `#middlediv` has `left: 15%` and is on top of `#leftdiv` and `#leftdiv` is actually wider than you can see it behind `#middlediv`.

I'm not sure if it fullfills all your requirements, but check this, I'm using a div wrapper with grid display so the left grid item has a width with `max-content`. Then the other two divs need to use the rest of the space so I put them inside another div. https://jsfiddle.net/n3o679pf/

EDIT: It can be cleaner using just a flex on the wrapper https://jsfiddle.net/n3o679pf/2/ so no need for that ugly `#therest` div I put using a grid.

```
<div id='header'></div>
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='leftdiv'>Contains links</div>
  <div id='middlediv'></div>
  <div id='rightdiv'></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top:60px;
  margin: 0;
}
#leftdiv{
    height:200px;
    background-color:#ED6062;
    min-width:200px;
}
#middlediv{
    width:35%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#F0E92B;
}
#rightdiv{
    width:65%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#26D978;
}
```

Comment: Your an absolute star thank you so much i've been going crazy for hours over this.